# Add Array Type value in Material Select in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to bind Array Type to Material Select in Angular Project but it is returning below error.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Value must be an array in multiple-selection mode.

Here is my code,

**Template**

```
<ng-template kendoRippleContainer kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem let-column="column" let-formGroup="formGroup">   

        <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Roles</mat-label>
                <mat-select [formControl]="formGroup.get(column.field)" multiple [(value)]="dataItem">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roleList" [value]="role._id">{{role.roleName}}</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>

      </ng-template>
```

**Typescript**

```
createFormGroup = dataItem => this.fb.group({
    '_id': new FormControl(dataItem._id),
    'roles': [new FormControl(dataItem.roles)]
  })
```

**Service returned JSON Object**

> createdDate: Thu Jul 25 2019 21:48:06 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
>
> {} methodAlias: "List Users" 
>   methodName: "list" methodType: "POST"
>   moduleName: "user" roles: 
>   Array(3) 0: 
>       {_id:
>   "5caf9fb37147ed08f3f538b3", roleName: "SuperAdmin"} 1: {_id:
>   "5caf9fc07147ed08f3f538b7", roleName: "Admin"} 2: {_id:
>   "5cafa9d72b4aaf0017bfef09", roleName: "Manager"} length: 3
>   **proto**: Array(0)
>   _id: "5d3a15861f276d6560ee7f55"

Comment: Could you provide stackblitz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pretty sure you just need to do this:

```
createFormGroup = dataItem => this.fb.group({
  '_id': [dataItem._id],
  'roles': [dataItem.roles.map(r => r._id)]
})
```

a multiple select wants a FormControl with an array value, adn the values need to match what you bind to the option values. not an array with a single FormControl in it, and the syntax of using formbuilder looks more like what I have here.. it's basically:

```
[key:string]: [value, validators, asyncValidators]
```

This may not be correct bc I'm not sure what `column.field` equals, it should be 'roles'

also take back the 2 way bind to value in your template, either use a one way bind, or don't use it at all since you're using a reactive form

Comment: Now the error is not there but the default values are not selected. any idea?

Comment: did you get rid of that 2 way bind on value?

Comment: yep tried `(value)="column.field"` and even removed as you suggested

Comment: nvm, see the issue. check my edit and try that, get rid of the overall value bind entirely.